# Find array with min value for key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array like this :

```
$array = 
[
    ['groupe' => 1510, 'nombre' => 3],
    ['groupe' => 1511, 'nombre' => 10],
    ['groupe' => 1512, 'nombre' => 5],
    ['groupe' => 1513, 'nombre' => 4],
    ['groupe' => 1514, 'nombre' => 3]
];
```

I want to find the min value for 'nombre' key and return its array. If many arrays have the same min value, I want to return only the first one.

How can I do this ? I found how to get the min value but I can't find how to return its array and only the first found.

To get min value :

```
$min = min(array_column($array, 'nombre'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    ['groupe' => 1510, 'nombre' => 3],
    ['groupe' => 1511, 'nombre' => 10],
    ['groupe' => 1512, 'nombre' => 5],
    ['groupe' => 1513, 'nombre' => 4],
    ['groupe' => 1514, 'nombre' => 3],
];

$min = null;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($min === null) {
        $min = $a;
    } elseif ($min['nombre'] > $a['nombre']) {
        $min = $a;
    }
}

// $min now contains what your are looking for.
```